# Locking multiple pages in AEM

Tags: aem

Is there a way to lock multiple pages at the same time, for example, a shortcut that will lock all the pages within a directory? To my understanding, the only way to lock pages is to manually open each one and lock from the sidekick. I haven't found anything in the documentation that indicates multiple page locking is possible. I'm working with AEM 5.6.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Page API's lock() method to lock a page: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/develop/ref/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/Page.html#lock()

And to lock multiple pages, you can iterate and lock one-by-one.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be to create a Groovy script to lock all the pages in a directory at once, and run it in Groovy Console.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that /libs/wcm/core/content/siteadmin/actions/lock has the property "context" with the value "[toolbar,contextmenu]". If not you need to overlay that and set the property accordingly.
Then from the Siteadmin you can select multiple (child) pages from the same "directory" and Lock/Unlock them at the same time.